# Backup & Restore h2 database

Tags: java, hibernate, backup, h2, database-restore

I'm little bit confused of how to perform h2 database "BACKUP" & "RESTORE".
I have write some code using hibernate and java, but this not working for now.
So, how to do backup & restore when database is used by the application.

```
File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(tbTabPaneHome.getScene().getWindow());
        if (file != null) {
            // Save file


            try {


                Session session = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.createSQLQuery("BACKUP TO '" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "'");
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                session.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's the error ? You just say "it is not working".

Comment: There is no, error. But it not produce any thing.It is excpected to create backup.zip file !

Answer (score 0):

You have created a query and not executed it, try running executeUpdate() on the created query

```
Session session = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("BACKUP TO '" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "'");
query.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```